# Preventing Opportunity stage changed based on amount and picklist value

Tags: validation-rule

I am needing assistance creating a validation rule preventing users from moving the Opportunity to a higher stage based on a picklist value being selected and the amount of the opportunity.

Example: Users should receive an error moving Opportunities past Research stage when the value of the Opportunity exceeds $250,000 AND the Doc Review Request field does not equal "Docs Approved". Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? [edit] your question to include your attempt as well as any errors that you're encountering. If you have a validation rule that isn't working, you should give us some example input, the expected output, and the output that you're observing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace 'Description' with your custom 'Doc Review Request' field and replace StageNames with your custom stage picklist values. The PRIORVALUE stages you will let users move to, and the ISPICKVAL stages will be restricted stages.

```
AND(
Amount > 250000,
Description != "Docs Approved",
OR(
ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(StageName), "Prospecting"),
ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(StageName), "Qualification"),
ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(StageName), "Needs Analysis"),
ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(StageName), "Prospecting")
),
OR(
ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Proposal/Price Quote"),
ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Negotiation/Review"),
ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Closed Won"),
ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Closed Lost")
)
)
```